# Thymeleaf format for list within a HashMap

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to put template which has a list of values within a key in a hashmap, However when I try to put it into the template if falls over into new row by itself.

Picture: 
[image: Problem]
Thymeleaf part of code:

```
    <div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">Boards</h1>
    <hr />
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Board Name</th>
            <th>Investor</th>
            <th>Fuse Manufacturer</th>
            <th>Fuse Nr. Of Poles</th>
            <th>Fuse Characteritics</th>
            <th>Fuse Amount</th>
        </tr>
        <th:block th:each="item, iterStat : ${map}" varStatus="status">
            <tr>
                <td th:text="${item.key.name}"></td>
                <td th:text="${item.key.investor}"></td>
                <tr th:each="fuse : ${item.value}">
                    <td th:text="${fuse.fuse.manufacturer.name}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${fuse.fuse.type}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${fuse.fuse.characteristics}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${fuse.quantity}"></td>
                </tr>
            </tr>
        </th:block>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: could you provide an image that describes what you want to archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating `<tr />`s in your `<tr />`s.  Looking at the source generated by thymeleaf should tell you this.  I would guess your html should look something like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>Board Name</th>
    <th>Investor</th>
    <th>Fuse Manufacturer</th>
    <th>Fuse Nr. Of Poles</th>
    <th>Fuse Characteritics</th>
    <th>Fuse Amount</th>
  </tr>

  <th:block th:each="item: ${map}">
    <tr th:each="fuse: ${item.value}">
      <td th:text="${item.key.name}" />
      <td th:text="${item.key.investor}" />
      <td th:text="${fuse.fuse.manufacturer.name}" />
      <td th:text="${fuse.fuse.type}" />
      <td th:text="${fuse.fuse.characteristics}" />
      <td th:text="${fuse.quantity}" />
    </tr>
  </th:block>
</table>
```